# Probabilities: $P(A)=1/2$, $P(A|B)=4/7$, $P(B|A)=2/5$, $P(A \cup B)=?$

Tags: probability, statistics

I've literally spent the past 5 hours trying to figure this out, and I just can't understand where some of these numbers are coming from.

For example-

If $P(A) = 1/2, P(A|B) = 4/7$, and $P(B|A) = 2/5$, find $P(A or B)$  (which the answer given is $0.65$.

From what I understand, to get $P(A \cup B)$, we need to do 
$P(A)+P(B)-P(A/B)$.

I guess I can get $P(B \cap A)$ since we have P(A) and P(B|A). I am just not sure how to go on about this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  P(B|A) = $\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$ As you say, that will give you the probability of both occurring...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write
$$
\begin{align}
P(A \cap B)&=P(B) \cdot P(A|B)=\frac47 P(B) \tag1 \\
P(A \cap B)&=P(A) \cdot P(B|A)=\frac25 P(A)=\frac25 \times \frac12 =\color{green}{\frac15} \tag2
\end{align}
$$ From $(1)$ and $(2)$ you deduce
$$
\frac47 P(B)=\frac15, \qquad P(B)=\color{blue}{\frac7{20}}
$$ Then recalling that
$$
P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)
$$ gives
$$
P(A \cup B)=\frac12+\color{blue}{\frac7{20}}-\color{green}{\frac15}
$$

> $$
> P(A \cup B)=\color{red}{\frac{13}{20}}.
> $$

Comment: @Kevin R. You may notice that $\color{red}{\dfrac{13}{20}}=0.65$